# Views 3 Relationship Handler

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-views-relationship

I am trying to write a relationship handler for Views 3 in Drupal 7, but am failing even to begin.

Basically, I have a bunch of nodes of various types all with the same field attached to them. This field is a reference field linking off to a Civicrm contact - but that's not important, as essentially these fields just contain integers.

Now, let's say I have a node of content type 'story', and its reference field contains the integer, oh, let's say 55. In addition, there are nodes of content type 'news' which also contain the reference ID 55.

I want to build a block view, that sits on the story page, that reads in the node's nid as its argument, and then through a relationship it discovers all other nodes that contain the same reference integer as itself.

(In my head, the sql looks something like: `SELECT n.nid FROM node n INNER JOIN node n2 ON n.reference = n2.reference` [Assuming, for the sake of simplicity, the field data is kept in the node table]).

How do I create a Views handler that caters for this relationship? The only documentation I can find is the views api, which is for version 2 and not 3, and besides is utterly unhelpful. Reading various module's views handlers is not helping either, and views tutorials on the web are almost non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing and what is the problem?  It sounds like you have everything you need right here...the nid as an argument and the reference field as a relationship.  What are your filters set to? and what display type are you using?  You could just have the block display some information without sorting, arguments, or relationships and then using the devel module you can change the tpl file for the block to dpm($views) and see what information you have access to.

Let us know what you have configured so far and what your results are if any.  Remember that you can use the nid as an argument in the preview, so if the nid is 213 you can type 213 in the preview field (make sure the display is set to the block you are talking about) and see what comes up.

Good luck.